# Iterating through data-attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not getting very far with the following, and am seeking an understanding of the process please.

I have this HTML

```
<span data-credit-name="Name_1"><strong>1</strong> Name 1</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_2"><strong>2</strong> Name 2</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_3"><strong>1</strong> Name 3</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_4"><strong>1</strong> Name 4</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_5"><strong>3</strong> Name 5</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_6"><strong>1</strong >Name 6</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_7"><strong>4</strong> Name 7</span><br />
```

What I would like to do is iterate through each span and collect its data-credit-name and the value within the strong tag and create a js object looking like so

```
var credit = {Name_1:"1", Name_2:"2", Name_3:"3"};
```

I've tried this to get the first one but get empty string returned:

```
var credit = $('span[data-credit-name]:first').text();
console.log(credit);
```

Comment: Do you mean `var credit = {Name 1:"1", Name 2:"2", Name 3:"1"};`?

Comment: @Satpal - using spaces is fine.  Try it and you'll see ;)   `var credit = { "Name 1":"1", "Name 2":"2", "Name 3":"1" }; console.log(credit);`

Comment: @Archer, Thanks I learned something today

Comment: No worries mate - I learn something new on here every day!

Comment: thanks to everyone who answered, it is much appreciated.I went with @kmoe for her use of the new markup for the example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the data attributes you should use the jQuery `.data()` method. You can iterate like so:

```
var credit = {};

$("span[data-credit-name]").each(function(){

   var key = $(this).data("credit-name");

   var value = $(this).find("strong").text();

  credit[key] = value;

});
```

```js
var credit = {};

$("span").each(function(){
  
   var key = $(this).data("credit-name");
 
  var value = $(this).find("strong").text();
  
  credit[key] = value;

});

console.log(credit);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-credit-name="Name_1"><strong>1</strong> Name 1</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_2"><strong>2</strong> Name 2</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_3"><strong>1</strong> Name 3</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_4"><strong>1</strong> Name 4</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_5"><strong>3</strong> Name 5</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_6"><strong>1</strong >Name 6</span><br />
<span data-credit-name="Name_7"><strong>4</strong> Name 7</span><br />
```

Comment: I really need to learn the markup for this site.  Shame on me :p

Comment: It's a pretty new feature :)

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick...

```
var credit = {};

$("span[data-credit-name]").each(function() {
    credit[$(this).data("credit-name")] = $(this).find("strong").text();
});
```

jsfiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/t9bthjg4/

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the desired values and use `get()` to unwrap the result from jQuery objects.

On top of my head:

```
var result = $('span[data-credit-name]').map(function(i, el){

var ret = {},
    $span = $(el),
    creditName = $span.data('credit-name');

    ret[creditName] = ++i; 
    return ret; 

}).get();

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5d09bo4c/2/

(Based on your latest HTML change in the question)

Answer (score 1):

```
var out = {};
$.each($('span'), function (i, el) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var strong = $this.find('strong').html();
  var data = $this.data('credit-name');
  out[data] = strong;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n21bh416/)